# Table Infinite Marquee Effect in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web, css-animations

I'm trying to make my table auto-scroll to the last row and then wrap around so that the first row comes after the last one is shown and the table continues scrolling infinitely. The table is supposed to showcase rankings and I want to make sure that users would not have to scroll manually if they want to see all the rankings. Although I do want to add a feature to make it possible to scroll manually too on hover.

I tried using a component from "react-fast-marquee" but I didn't get the result I wanted, and it felt very weird to implement.

This is the code that I have for now:

table.tsx:

```
import { Ranking, Column } from "./columns";

export function Table({ data, columns }: any) {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr className="sticky z-10 top-0 bg-white text-left">
          {columns.map((column: Column, index: number) => (
            <th key={index} className="p-4">
              {column.header}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody className="table_scroll">
        {data.map((country: Ranking, index: number) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            {Object.keys(country).map((key: string, index: number) => (
              <td key={index} className="p-4">
                {country[key as keyof Ranking]}
              </td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

styles.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@keyframes verticalMarquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}

.table_scroll {
  animation: verticalMarquee 40s linear infinite;
}

.table_scroll:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

this is a codesanbox link to what I have so far:
https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-night-wtz5dt?file=/src/index.js

I recreated things quickly in codesandbox and didn't really put time to figure out why tailwind styles were not working but it should not interfere with the main issue that I am asking about.

I am using tailwind css in my final app but while I was testing how to implement the maruee feature I found it quicker to try things using regular css especially when creating keyframes, this is why there is a mixture of both for now.